# Matlab Confidence Interval with normfit/fitdist/paramci differ from manual calculation depending on the number of elements. Why?

Tags: matlab, statistics, intervals, confidence-interval

I am testing some confidence interval calculation, however, I have noticed differences using the Matlab functions `normfit/fitdist/paramci` from the manual calculation. Please have a look to the code below, and test the `data` with more elements. As the data size increases the differences are smaller. Does someone have a clue/solution/explanation?

Thanks

Will

```
%% Cleaning service
  clear all; close all;

  %% Data and processing
  conf = norminv([0.025 0.975],0,1); % for 95%

  data = normrnd(0.158,0.0265,10,1); % Change the third argument to 100, 1000, 1000, ...
  [mu,sigma,muci,sigmaci] = normfit(data,.05);               % for 95%  
  pd = fitdist(data,'Normal'); ci = paramci(pd,'Alpha',.05); % for 95%

  xplus  = mu + conf(2)*sigma*(1/sqrt(length(data)));
  xminus = mu - conf(2)*sigma*(1/sqrt(length(data)));

  Difference = [ci(1,1)-xminus ci(2,1)-xplus]
```

Answer (score 0):

A "typical" confidence interval for a mean will actually use critical values from the t-distribution, not the normal - this will mean slightly wider intervals, wider at small sample sizes. As sample size increases, the t critical values converge to the normal critical values. I'm not a Matlab programmer these days, but I'd be curious if a canned function such as `paramci` will use the t-distribution instead of the normal.

So, this work is in R, not Matlab, but I'm hoping that I'll produce some numbers you'll recognize.  Let's say for a sample of size n=10, mean=5, sd=2...

```
n <- 10
mn <- 5
sd <- 2
```

A 95% CI using normal critical values would be constructed "by hand" like so:

```
mn + qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975))*sd/sqrt(n)
# 3.76041 6.23959
```

and a 95% CI using t critical values like so:

```
mn + qt(c(0.025, 0.975), n-1)*sd/sqrt(n)
# 3.569286 6.430714  
# ...note slightly wider
```

At n=500, the two become indistinguishable.

```
n <- 500
mn + qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975))*sd/sqrt(n)
# 4.824695 5.175305
mn + qt(c(0.025, 0.975), n-1)*sd/sqrt(n)
# 4.824269 5.175731
```

These are all manual calculations that I'm hoping will match what Matlab does in a similar scenario.  If not ... then I can always retract my answer ;)